# Using MediaStream from WebRTC with an AnalyserNode

Tags: html, google-chrome, webrtc, web-audio-api

`AnalyserNode`s work perfectly with `MediaStream`s of `getUserMedia`. But I can't get Chrome to analyse `MediaStream`s I got from `RTCPeerConnection.onaddstream`. Calling `.getByteFrequencyData` creates an array of zeros:

```
pc.onaddstream = function(evt) {
    var conn = _conns[user];
    conn.audio = $('<audio>', {
        src: URL.createObjectURL(evt.stream),
        autoplay: true
    });

    conn.context = Microphone.context();
    conn.sourceNode = conn.context.createMediaStreamSource(evt.stream);
    conn.analyserNode = conn.context.createAnalyser();
    conn.sourceNode.connect(conn.analyserNode);

    conn.analyserInterval = setInterval(function() {
        var bufferLength = conn.analyserNode.frequencyBinCount;
        var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
        conn.analyserNode.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
        console.log(dataArray);
    }, 50);
};
```

Replacing the parameter of `createMediaStreamSource` with `Microphone.stream()` which is the stream I got from `getUserMedia` fills the array with data.

I'm using Chrome 47 on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it's not yet implemented: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121673.

Comment: Okay, and what about Firefox?

Comment: It works, but make sure to keep a reference to your `PeerConnection` stream somewhere, we have a bug where it's garbage collected too early otherwise.